# lapack.so 'missing' make-ing R from src

Tags: r

I've run into an odd problem building R from scratch.  lapack.so is not being found but it is present.  I've hit the same problem building R-3.2.3 and R-3.2.4. (I'm doing this on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.)

./configure runs with no errors.
When I run make, all the compilation appears to get done successfully.  However, later I on get

```
byte-compiling package 'grDevices'
Warning in solve.default(rgb) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/modules//lapack.so':
  /home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/modules//lapack.so: undefined symbol: dpotrf_
Error in solve.default(rgb) : LAPACK routines cannot be loaded
Error: unable to load R code in package 'grDevices'
Execution halted
make[4]: *** [../../../library/grDevices/R/grDevices.rdb] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/src/library/grDevices'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/src/library/grDevices'
make[2]: *** [R] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/src/library'
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/src'
make: *** [R] Error 1
```

Note the line

```
unable to load shared object '/home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/modules//lapack.so':
```

A file /home/moi/apps/R/R-3.2.3/modules/lapack.so
does exist, but that double slash "//" looks wrong.

Any thoughts about how to fix this would be appreciated.

thanks

PS Please do not suggest that I use precompiled binaries.  I really do need to build from src.

Comment: ps make did produce an executable that runs, but during startup it reports that several things are missing, including graphics.

Comment: Why do you do this?  Why don't you install a current, properly configured R 3.2.4 from [the Ubuntu section of CRAN](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu) ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel is there any know fix for that? installing `liblapack-dev` did not help

Comment: As I said, if it breaks, you get to keep the pieces. We support properly build binary for all flavors, in the distros (Debian/Ubuntu) and via PPA and backports at CRAN. Works for me.  For people who insist on doing it themselves, a full manual exists in the R sources. Or you can cheat and use my scripts (by peeking at the [Debian package sources](https://salsa.debian.org/edd/r-base) on our git repo).

Comment: It looks like a bug in configure/make instructions. Files are there, only path is broken @DirkEddelbuettel and still valid as of R 3.5.0

Comment: Jan, please: How is anyone supposed to work off some ten word comments at a years old ticket.  I don't have to tell you about _minimally reproducible examples_ do I?  Now let's leave this ticket alone.

Comment: @jangorecki if you have the original `undefined symbol: dpotrf_` problem, maybe you aren't set up with Fortran properly...

Comment: looks like installing `gfortran` did make this issue disappear. That should be ideally handled by apt-get install build deps of R.